# Persisting TemporaryFile in Python without rewriting it | Call linkstat in python on fd

Tags: python, python-3.x, posix, ctypes, cpython

I have a library that provides me with a `TemporaryFile` object which I would like to persist on the file system it was stored, **without rewriting it**: The file could be quite huge and performance is critical. I am working in an Linux/POSIX environment.

The [tempfile documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) explains that the temporary file is created using the `O_TMPFILE` attribute. Doing this the file has no visible file name in the directory listing.

According to the [Linux manpage about O_TMPFILE](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/manpages-dev/open.2.en.html#O_TMPFILE) it is possible to use the C call `linkat(fd, "", AT_FDCWD, "/path/for/file", AT_EMPTY_PATH);` to persist the file.

How can I achieve this in Python?

*(I am aware that python probably unlinks the file, once the file opener is closed. But unlinking, as the name suggest doesn't delete the file, just the record in the directory listing, so the second created listing should remain).*

#### What I have tried

Unfortunately `os.link`, even so it uses `linkstat` in the background does not support to be fed with a  file link.

```py
import tempfile
import os

# Ensure we save tempfile to the correct block device (the same we want to create the hardlink at)
tempfile.tempdir = "/home/user/tmp"
file = tempfile.TemporaryFile()

# Add some content to the file, so it isn't empty
file.write(b"Das ist ein TEst")

os.link(file, "/home/user/tmp/test.txt")
# -> TypeError: link: src should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not BufferedRandom

os.link(file.raw, "/home/user/tmp/test.txt")
# -> TypeError: TypeError: link: src should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not FileIO

os.link(os.link(file.raw.fileno(), "/home/user/tmp/test.txt")
# -> TypeError: link: src should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not int
```

I seems I need to call `linkstat` directly, but I don't know how.
Is this possible without compiling a Python C extension? Maybe using [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html)?

#### Background

Before people ask, why I do no simply use: [`NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36968297/3813064) ⇒ I don't have power over the creation of the temporary file.
It is created in Starlette during [FileUploads](https://www.starlette.io/requests/#request-files) and I want to directly use it [without the hassle of creating my own stream file handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73443824/3813064).
Starlette already handles the streaming and rendering very well, it just [gives no possibility](https://github.com/encode/starlette/issues/388) [to change the details of the rendering behaviour](https://github.com/encode/starlette/issues/849).

The [O_TMPFILE documentation](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/manpages-dev/open.2.en.html#O_TMPFILE) states this option is used for two main reason, one of them:

> Creating a file that is initially invisible, which is
> then populated with data and adjusted to have
> appropriate filesystem attributes (fchown(2),
> fchmod(2), fsetxattr(2), etc.)  before being atomically
> linked into the filesystem in a fully formed state
> (using linkat(2) as described above).

Which is exactly what I want to achieve in my use case.

Comment: if you can install extra modules. there's https://pypi.org/project/linkat/ - its old so might not work but at least it can point you to right direction if you need to implement one yourself

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I can actually call `linkat` using this old pkg. But I get a `FileNotFoundError`. Reading the linkat docstring and the manpage again, my idea might not work, as `O_EXCL` is used to create the file and the manpage states: "If O_EXCL is **not specified**, then linkat(2) can be used to link the temporary file into the filesystem, making it permanent"

So probably is simply not possible. Bummer.

Comment: Hmm but I even can't get it to work with a `NamedTemporaryFile`...